# Problem with copy files using cmd in Java

Tags: java, windows, command-line, process, runtime

I'm trying to copy a bunch of files with a specific extension from one folder to another using the `copy` command, heres wat im doing,

```
 String[] command = new String[3];
 command[0] = "cmd";
 command[1] = "/c";
 command[2] = "copy C:\\output\\html\\*.txt C:\\output\\";

 ProcessBuilder copyFiles = new ProcessBuilder(command);
 p = copyFiles.start();
 p.waitFor();
```

the thing is, this code works fine for files less than some 5 or so, but just stops responding wen the number of files are more (even for 15 files) !! and the files are not copied either!!
I dont know what the problem is, will be glad if someone could help! :)

Comment: Does running that command from a Command window with more than 15 txt files in that directory cause it to stop responding? Or does this ONLY happen when the command is called from JVM?

Comment: @keepitreall89 , from command window its working fine! only from jvm its giving probs..

Comment: A possible solution would be to add the /Y flag in your command[2] string after "C:\\output\\" this would prevent it from trying to ask you if you want to overwrite a file with the same name. The problem could be that a file with that name already exists and so it askes if you want to overwrite it, only your java call doesn't "listen" for that.

Comment: is there a reason that you need to do this from cmd, or would just using java to copy the files be acceptable too?

Comment: @keepitreall89 tried the /Y flag, moreover a prev method deletes all the files in that folder, so theres no possibility of having a file already, and ya after the above process, i hav to make one more similar one, which has to be done using DOS!!

Comment: @Hari Have you tried commenting out the p.waitFor()? I have use the process objects of java several times and never used that method, but I haven't had reason to multithread any of them either.

Comment: @keepitreal89:  I ran the OP's code without the `p.waitFor()` line.  That got rid of the hanging, but I found that no files were copied.

Comment: yup luke is write, if we dont wait for it to finish, the files wil not be copied (atleast not all files) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not reading the output the `copy` command is generating.

When spawning a child process using ProcessBuilder, output generated by your child process gets written to a buffer.  If this buffer isn't read from, it eventually fills up.  When it fills up, the `copy` command can't write any more to it and so is blocked by the operating system.  It is then forced to wait until space is made in the buffer by reading from it.

I ran your code with 20 files and I found that it did indeed hang.

One way to solve your problem is to redirect the output from `copy` to `NUL`.  Most of the output from `copy` is a list of all the files it has copied, which you probably don't care too much for.  To do this redirection, modify the line that assigns to `command[2]` to the following:

```
command[2] = "copy C:\\output\\html\\*.txt C:\\output\\ >NUL 2>NUL";
```

However, if there is a problem copying files, you might not know about it if you do this.

Alternatively, you can read the output that the `copy` command generates.   The following code sends it to `System.out`, but you can easily send it elsewhere or completely ignore it if you wish:

```
String[] command = { "cmd", "/c", "copy C:\\output\\html\\*.txt C:\\output\\" };
ProcessBuilder copyFiles = new ProcessBuilder(command);
copyFiles.redirectErrorStream(true);
p = copyFiles.start();

// The InputStream we get from the Process reads from the standard output
// of the process (and also the standard error, by virtue of the line
// copyFiles.redirectErrorStream(true) ).
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
do {
    line = reader.readLine();
    if (line != null) { System.out.println(line); }
} while (line != null);
reader.close();

p.waitFor();
```

I gave each approach a quick test with the same 20 files and neither approach hung.

**EDIT**: You might also want to try a 'hybrid' approach, by throwing away what `copy` writes to standard output (e.g. the list of files it's copying) but using the second approach to read in what it writes to standard error (e.g. error messages).  To do this, you'd add the `>NUL`, which redirects the standard output of `copy` to `NUL`, but you wouldn't add the `2>NUL`, since that redirects standard error to `NUL`.

Comment: woodward , thanks a lot and, im accepting this as an answer,i was actually trying this buffered reader method, and i understood the second approach, but in the first, why is it redirected twice? is there any significance?? :)

Comment: @Hari: All processes have a standard output and a standard error stream for writing to, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams.  Using `>NUL` and `2>NUL` redirects both the standard output and standard error streams to `NUL`.  You can't redirect them both together.  Of course, if `copy` writes a lot to its standard error stream, and you don't read from its standard error, it will hang.